# How do I get the name of the container to show instead of the id?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

So I am trying to figure out how to display the ForeignKey name in the view I have thought about using map method and get the object from the ID and getting the name from said ID, but that doesn't seem to work. I could be doing it wrong but I am not quite sure.

JSON Response

```json
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Coke",
        "description": "Cocaine Drink",
        "container": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Another One",
        "description": "Dj Khaled Drink",
        "container": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Testy",
        "description": "Westy",
        "container": 4
    }
]
```

View

```py
class ListDrinks(APIView):

    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []
    
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        drinks = Drink.objects.all()
        serializer = DrinkSerializer(map(DrinksId, drinks), many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = DrinkSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Models

```py
class Container(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Drink(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    container = models.ForeignKey(
        Container, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Serializers

```py
class DrinkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Drink
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'description', 'container']


class ContainerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Container
        fields = ['id', 'name']
```

Comment: Can you add the `DrinkSerializer` code to your question? It's the `Drink.container` FK you are talking about, no?

Comment: Added the Serializer Code, and yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can use [ListCreateAPIView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listcreateapiview) for your view check it later.

And for your question check [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) out and
update the `DrinkSerializer` to this

```py
class DrinkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    container = serializers.CharField(source="container.name", read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Drink
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'description', 'container']
```

And you can do this, I think is better.

```py
    ...
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = DrinkSerializer(Drink.objects.all(), many=True)
        ...
```